# Get date difference between first date of a group and last date of previous group in R

Tags: r, dplyr, data-manipulation, lubridate

I have a dataset that looks like that:

```
x = data.frame(id = c("A","A","A","A","B","B","B","B"), group = c(1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4),
               date1 = c("25/03/2017",  "26/03/2017","03/04/2017","04/04/2017",
                         "04/05/2017","26/08/2017","28/08/2017","30/08/2017"),    
               date2 = c("26/03/2017","29/03/2017","04/04/2017","04/05/2017",
                         "18/05/2017","28/08/2017","29/08/2017","31/08/2017")
                )
> x
  id group      date1      date2
1  A     1 25/03/2017 26/03/2017
2  A     1 26/03/2017 29/03/2017
3  A     2 03/04/2017 04/04/2017
4  A     2 04/04/2017 04/05/2017
5  B     3 04/05/2017 18/05/2017
6  B     3 26/08/2017 28/08/2017
7  B     4 28/08/2017 29/08/2017
8  B     4 30/08/2017 31/08/2017
```

What I would like to do is for each person to get the date difference in days of the first date in date1 in the second group and the last date in date2 of the previous group. So for example, person with id = A, I want to get days difference of "03/04/2017" and "29/03/2017". Same for patient B. I have multiple groups within each person. 
I would like to end up with a dataset like that:

```
y = data.frame(id = c("A","A","B","B"), group = c(1,2,3,4),
               date1 = c("26/03/2017","03/04/2017","26/08/2017","28/08/2017"),    
               date2 = c("29/03/2017","04/04/2017","28/08/2017","29/08/2017"),
               datediff = c(NA,5,NA,0)
              ) 
> y
  id group      date1      date2 datediff
1  A     1 26/03/2017 29/03/2017       NA
2  A     2 03/04/2017 04/04/2017        5
3  B     3 26/08/2017 28/08/2017       NA
4  B     4 28/08/2017 29/08/2017        0
```

I have looked around a lot for that and found and answer for subtracting first and last observation withing the same group but nothing about the last and first of different groups. Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Not clear how general you want the solution to be. Are you ALWAYS going to have 2 groups per `id`, where each group has 2 rows?

Comment: I don't have always 2 groups per id and not always 2 ids. This was just an example of my dataset for illustration. I mentioned I have multiple groups within id, but maybe I should have been clearer. I want to have the solution as generic as possible.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a more general approach that should work with 3+ groups per `id` and/or 3+ rows per group:

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

# update dates (if needed)
x = x %>% mutate_at(vars(matches("date")), dmy)

# get appropriate rows based on first group 
x1 = x %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  filter(group == min(group)) %>%
  filter(date1 == max(date1)) %>%
  ungroup()

# get appropriate rows based on last group 
x2 = x %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  filter(group == max(group)) %>%
  filter(date2 == min(date2)) %>%
  ungroup()

# combine datasets and calculate date difference
x1 %>%
  bind_rows(x2) %>%
  arrange(id, group) %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(datediff = as.numeric(date1 - lag(date2))) %>%
  ungroup()

# # A tibble: 4 x 5
#   id    group date1      date2      datediff
#   <fct> <dbl> <date>     <date>        <dbl>
# 1 A         1 2017-03-26 2017-03-29       NA
# 2 A         2 2017-04-03 2017-04-04        5
# 3 B         3 2017-08-26 2017-08-28       NA
# 4 B         4 2017-08-28 2017-08-29        0
```

Answer (score 0):

Parse your string dates using `lubridate::dmy`. Then you can use `dplyr` to calculate the difference between `date1` and the lagged values of `date2`.
In the end, filter for those rows, which represent new groups.

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
x = data.frame(id = c("A","A","A","A","B","B","B","B"), group = c(1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4),
               date1 = dmy(c("25/03/2017",  "26/03/2017","03/04/2017","04/04/2017",
                         "04/05/2017","26/08/2017","28/08/2017","30/08/2017")),    
               date2 = dmy(c("26/03/2017","29/03/2017","04/04/2017","04/05/2017",
                         "18/05/2017","28/08/2017","29/08/2017","31/08/2017"))
)



x %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  filter(group != lag(group) | group != lead(group)) %>%
  mutate(diff = date1 - lag(date2)) %>%
  ungroup()



# A tibble: 4 x 5
  id    group date1      date2      diff     
  <fct> <dbl> <date>     <date>     <time>   
1 A         1 2017-03-26 2017-03-29 NA days  
2 A         2 2017-04-03 2017-04-04 " 5 days"
3 B         3 2017-08-26 2017-08-28 NA days  
4 B         4 2017-08-28 2017-08-29 " 0 days"
```

And if you want numeric output, use `mutate(diff = as.numeric(date1 - lag(date2)))`. As long as your data is sorted (`x <- x[with(x, order(id, group)), ]`) it should work fine no matter how many persons and groups.